# How to split a string into parts that each part contains only same characters in python

Tags: python

I want to get a sequence of DNA as a string and i need to split the string into parts of a list.And each part must contain same characters only.And final output must be a list according to the order of the original sequence using python 3.4

Ex:-  `infected ="AATTTGCCAAA"`
I need to get the output as followed

```
Modified.  = ['AA','TTT','G','CC','AAA' ]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Seems like a simple task.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't mention that i need to implement an algorithm to do this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fchar(ch,mi):
    global numLi
    fc=ch
    li=""
    for c in infected[mi:]:
        if fc==c :
            li+=fc
            mi = mi+1
        else:
            break

    if mi<len(infected) :
        return li+" "+fchar(infected[mi],mi)
    else:
        return li

infected =input("Enter DNA sequence\n") ;#"AAATTTTTTTTGCCCCCCA"
x=fchar(infected[0],0)         
newSet = x.split(' ')
print(newSet)
```

Comment: thanx a lot,, actually i needed only the algorithm to implement this,, so code means a lot

Answer (score 4):

It's what that [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is for :

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> infected ="AATTTGCCAAA"
>>> 
>>> [''.join(g) for _,g in groupby(infected)]
['AA', 'TTT', 'G', 'CC', 'AAA']
```

Comment: Thanx sir .It is also working..I need to know  whether groupby is a built in package in python.?

Comment: @ThilinaChathuranga Welcome, `group` by is not a built in function  your need to import it from `itertools` module which is one of python default modules.

Comment: @Kasramvd : thanx a lot,, it seems easy. But actually i need to make an algorithm and implement what i need.because it is a pastpaper question which asked for the algorithm.So i can't  import and use predefined functions.Anyway thanx